# Updating sequences for a single schema not working (Postgres 12)

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-12

**Postgresql12**

I am trying to fix a schema's sequences, but for some reason this yields attributes from other tables in some cases. I assume I am leaving out something in the where clause that isn't limiting the results to the sequence columns I expect:

```
SELECT 'SELECT SETVAL(' ||
       quote_literal(quote_ident(PGT.schemaname) || '.' || quote_ident(S.relname)) ||
       ', COALESCE(MAX(' ||quote_ident(C.attname)|| '), 1) ) FROM ' ||
       quote_ident(PGT.schemaname)|| '.'||quote_ident(T.relname)|| ';'
FROM pg_class AS S,
     pg_depend AS D,
     pg_class AS T,
     pg_attribute AS C,
     pg_tables AS PGT,
     pg_namespace AS N
WHERE S.relkind = 'S'
      AND N.nspname = 'my_schema'
      AND S.oid = D.objid
      AND S.relnamespace = N.oid
      AND D.refobjid = T.oid
      AND D.refobjid = C.attrelid
      AND D.refobjsubid = C.attnum
      AND T.relnamespace = N.oid
      AND T.relname = PGT.tablename
      AND PGT.schemaname = 'my_schema'
ORDER BY S.relname;
```

Must be something obvious, just not seeing it.

Comment: The obvious is that the query is a mess. You are pulling duplicate information from multiple tables doing unspecified joins.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know what the fix is supposed to be doing?